# Hyperloop for Bluetooth LE communication in iOS app?

Tags: appcelerator, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-mobile, appcelerator-hyperloop

Can anyone point me to some examples or direction on how I could use Hyperloop to integrate a bluetooth device in my Titanium iOS app? Seems like it should be possible but I've never done Objective-C or native iOS development and I'm not sure the best way to go about it.

Comment: There are some available on the marketplace, eg. the Bluetooth Low Energy Protocol Module from Logical Labs